# UPDATE sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-update, hazelcast

Having trouble executing "UPDATE" sql statement in hazelcast cluster:

Whenever try to use "UPDATE" sql statement combined with "EXISTS" condition like:

```
UPDATE table_A T1
SET name="A"
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table_B T2
              WHERE T1.id=T2.parent_id)
```

will get exception like:

```
There are not enough rules to produce a node with desired properties: convention=LOGICAL, sort=(],
DistributionTraitDef=ANY. All the inputs have relevant nodes, however the cost is still infinite.
```

Could anyone maybe give a hint about what's going wrong?

Comment: I suggest filing an issue with Hazelcast. Looks like this combination is not supported, but the error message should say it. This one is more like an internal error. Which Hazelcast version are you using?

Comment: latest version 5.1.1